# SAT preserving conversion of statement to existential one

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, decidability

For me, a formula $\psi$ is **existential** if and only if it is of the form $\psi=\exists x_1\cdots\exists x_n \varphi$ such that $\varphi$ has no quantifiers.

**Prove or Disprove**: There exists an algorithm that given a statement $\alpha$ outputs an **existential** statement $\beta$ such that $\alpha$ is satisfiable if and only if $\beta$ is satisfiable.

I have heard about Herbrandization but it only preserves validity as far as I know...

Comment: @HenningMakholm As far as I know it is Skolemization that preserves satisfiability and output of universal sentence (?)

Comment: Yeah, I misremembered the name.

Comment: Better hint: It looks like satisfiability of existential formulas is algorithmically decidable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm How so? I think that we can take the Skolemization and we end up with a statement without variables and without quantifiers so then we can use reduction to propositional calculus?

Comment: x @TrueTopologist, yes, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: The correspondence between the above comments and the question is far from clear. What has the **question** to do with decidability?

Comment: @RobArthan The thing is that if such an algorithm exists, then one can use it to decide satisfiability by skolemizing the result and applying the reduction to propositional logic. So, since satisfiability is not decidable in general the algorithm doesn't exist.

Comment: You should write this up in full as an answer.